# Does OS.shell_open("http://webpage") work on Android?

Tags: hyperlink, godot, gdscript

I am working on something like a one click hyperlinks ( I mean, like an icon that when clicked takes you to a webpage) for multi - device with godot and I fount this

```
OS.shell_open("http://webpage")
```

At the official godot q&a page, but I don't know if it works for Android

Does it work? Should I use another code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works on Android. I've tested and tried it myself.

```
OS.shell_open("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

This works on all platforms native to the Godot Engine.

Comment: which version of android did you use?

Comment: @MarsupialEntertainment A Pocophone F1 running Android 10.0. From what I found you should be fine with any recent Android release.

Comment: Thank you bro it was pretty useful